# Uuse both a manifest.mf and also pass jars using cp?

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I have a jar that uses a manifest for some of its dependencies which are packed up into a jar using maven.

Is it possible to run the jar with both the internal packaged up jars, which are described in the manifest, and jars that I pass using -cp at application launch?

Or is it one or the other?

Comment: To answer a slightly different question, if you use `java -jar` the `-cp` option is ignored.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956767/where-to-define-the-classpath-for-server-side-jars-manifest-mf-versus-cli-argu